# Simple foreach loop

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
$summize = new summize;
$search = $summize->search('#test');

$text = $search->results[0]->text;
```

`$text` stores the result, but only the first result of the array.

How ca a write a loop to go through all the values and output through say echo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
foreach ($search->results as $result) { echo $result->text; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you:

```
$n=0;
while ($text = $search->results[$n]){
   echo "[$text->text]<br>";
   $n++;
}
```

Comment: I guess he asks for a **foreach** loop example.

Comment: this is an infinite loop: you never advance to the next item of the array …